# JavaScript for-loop example from MDN not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was trying to run an example from MDN about for-loop in javaScript and for some reason it is not working. Here it is the code from [MDN Loops and Iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement):

```
<script>
function howMany(selectObject) {
  var numberSelected = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObject.options[i].selected) {
      numberSelected++;
    }
  }
  return numberSelected;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert('Number of options selected: ' + howMany(document.selectForm.musicTypes))
});
</script>

<form name="selectForm">
  <p>
    <label for="musicTypes">Choose some music types, then click the button below:</label>
    <select id="musicTypes" name="musicTypes" multiple="multiple">
      <option selected="selected">R&B</option>
      <option>Jazz</option>
      <option>Blues</option>
      <option>New Age</option>
      <option>Classical</option>
      <option>Opera</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input id="btn" type="button" value="How many are selected?" /></p>
</form>
```

I put it inside a html document and tried to run it. Then I got an    error that the button, which I was trying to reach by id is not null,    so I switched the places of the script and the html code.

When I ran it again it did not work and in the Firefox console it was written that the `selectObject` parameter in the function is `undefined`. 
I think that `howMany(document.selectForm.musicTypes)` is `undefined` and the alert    is not popping out. Does anyone have some suggestions why this might    be?

Comment: [The code works fine when it comes after the HTML.](http://jsfiddle.net/j77bxkj7/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor example from MDN. The reason it's not working is that your script is executed before your DOM elements are rendered. That means it won't find the button (because it doesn't exist) and the rest of your code won't be run.

Move the script tag after the HTML or inside of an on-ready event.

Example: http://jsbin.com/kotoziqaco/1/edit

Comment: His paragraph below the code says he moved the code, and then is now getting a different error.

Comment: You're right, but the OP did claim to have tried that.

Comment: i do not agree that it is poor, i think this is a good example of how hostile the web environment is.

Comment: I'm not sure why he'd say that. In the JSbin I linked I did just that and it works.

Comment: It's not *hostile* of me to say that the example is poor. (I didn't say it with any malice.) I think it's poor because it won't work if run as-is. That's (obviously) confusing for people who are learning JavaScript.

Comment: There must be other issue that's not represented in his question.

Comment: I'm trying to fix that MDN page but the MDN wiki software is so relentlessly terrible that I'm having a hard time making it readable.

Comment: That's good of you Pointy! Thanks for doing that. PS. "relentlessly terrible" sounds more hostile than "poor" ;)

Comment: @brianvaughn it's just amazing (and disappointing) :/  Anyway it's fixed now - I just moved the `<script>` to the end.  (It's still kind-of dumb but I don't have enough coffee in me to come up with something better.)

Answer (score 0):

put the script after the html, this is because the script fires before the html.

P.S

Do not put the script inside the form, just after the form like this

```
<form name="selectForm">
  <p>
    <label for="musicTypes">Choose some music types, then click the button below:</label>
    <select id="musicTypes" name="musicTypes" multiple="multiple">
      <option selected="selected">R&B</option>
      <option>Jazz</option>
      <option>Blues</option>
      <option>New Age</option>
      <option>Classical</option>
      <option>Opera</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input id="btn" type="button" value="How many are selected?" /></p>
</form>
<script>
function howMany(selectObject) {
  var numberSelected = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObject.options[i].selected) {
      numberSelected++;
    }
  }
  return numberSelected;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert('Number of options selected: ' + howMany(document.selectForm.musicTypes))
});
</script>
```

Comment: i think she moved the script into the form :)

Comment: But the event handler is being assigned, which means that it's at least below the `btn` element, which means it should work. Inside the `form` is ok.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<script>
function howMany(selectObject) {
    var numberSelected = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObject.options[i].selected) {
            numberSelected++;
        }
    }
    return numberSelected;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert('Number of options selected: ' + howMany(document.selectForm.musicTypes))
    });
});
</script>
```